# Auto populate text into text box with Yammer embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, yammer

Is there a way to auto populate your own text in the textbox that you type in your post/comment? For example a hashtag or such? Using Yammer embed

I used to be able to do so with JavaScript/jQuery but with the recent API update I am no longer able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the promptText in the config. This example is from the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/connect/):

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
 container: "#embedded-feed",
 feedType: "open-graph",
 config: {
   promptText: "Comment on this customer"
 }
});
```